# why does this assembly code not work in dosbox and how can i make it work?

Tags: assembly, dosbox

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
num1 db 3
num2 db 5
max db 0
.code
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
    mov num1, al

    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
    mov num2, al

    cmp num1, num2
    jg greater
    mov max, num2
    jmp done
greater:
    mov max, num1
done:
    mov dl, max
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
end start
```

I get this errors:

**Error** 100.asm(22) Illegal memory reference
**Error** 100.asm(24) Need register in expression
**Error** 100.asm(27) Need register in expression

,mentioning that the name of my file is 100.asm

I wanted to take 2 numbers as input and compare them to find the maximum value but i get this:
quick mention is that my file is named 100.asm

Comment: I don't know which line is 22, but e.g. `mov max, num2` is not valid - you can't move directly from one memory location to another on x86 - you have to go through a register.

Comment: the lines with the errors are these:
mov max, num1
mov dl, max
mov ax, 4c00h. Can you kindly tell me how to go through a director in order to make the code to work?

Comment: `mov ax, 4c00h` is valid syntax for a valid instruction.  You have 3 instructions with two memory operands each, enough to account for your 3 error messages, and the line numbers match up with them, not the `mov ax, imm16`.  What do you mean "director"?  500-internal said "register".  x86 has 7 registers other than the stack pointer; use some of them instead of keeping `max` in memory and then this will just work.

Comment: Technically, you haven't even made it to DOSBOX yet. This is the assembler giving you the error. Assembly runtime errors tend to cause unexpected behavior or a crash.

Comment: Something like `mov bl, num2` followed by `mov max, bl` would work.